# Blender Crashes when trying to start applying materials is there a fix or workaround?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

so whenever I try to begin applying materials to an object in blender it crashes. The object is about 5"x2"x1" so its not big at all and when I click on materials and click new material it instantly crashes. So I know its not the image I am trying to apply as a texture because I cannot make it that far before it crashes. Also there is no error or crash report that I have found so if one is generated please tell me where it is located and I can upload that. Is there anyway to fix this problem or a workaround that fixes it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the blender version, operating system, video card?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Blender Render,try applying material while using Cyles Render

Comment: Version 2.75, windows 7, & amd radeon hd 5470...i am trying to use cycles render

Comment: please reopen this question...i just started trying to learn blender and this is making it near impossible to do so.